# Failed to start the ocaml-jupyter kernal in jupyter notebook in windows 10

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ocaml, jupyter, opam

I have installled ocaml 64 and cygwin64 terminal in Windows 10. I have completely set the kernel by using this steps https://github.com/akabe/ocaml-jupyter.. But I got the kernel error in the top right corner of the jupyter notebook.

I have used ocaml kernel version 4.12.0+ mingw64. Can anyone help me to fix this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1704, in _execute
result = await result
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info) # type: ignore
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 69, in post
model = yield maybe_future(
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run
value = future.result()
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info) # type: ignore
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 98, in create_session
kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run
value = future.result()
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info) # type: ignore
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel_for_session
kernel_id = yield maybe_future(
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run
value = future.result()
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 176, in start_kernel
kernel_id = await maybe_future(self.pinned_superclass.start_kernel(self, **kwargs))
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\utils.py", line 25, in wrapped
return loop.run_until_complete(coro(*args, **kwargs))
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 70, in run_until_complete
return f.result()
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 201, in result
raise self._exception
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 256, in __step
result = coro.send(None)
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 186, in _async_start_kernel
self._add_kernel_when_ready(kernel_id, km, ensure_async(km.start_kernel(**kwargs)))
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\utils.py", line 25, in wrapped
return loop.run_until_complete(coro(*args, **kwargs))
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 70, in run_until_complete
return f.result()
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 201, in result
raise self._exception
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 256, in __step
result = coro.send(None)
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 335, in _async_start_kernel
await ensure_async(self._launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw))
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\utils.py", line 25, in wrapped
return loop.run_until_complete(coro(*args, **kwargs))
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 70, in run_until_complete
return f.result()
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 201, in result
raise self._exception
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 256, in __step
result = coro.send(None)
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 257, in _async_launch_kernel
connection_info = await self.provisioner.launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\provisioning\local_provisioner.py", line 179, in launch_kernel
self.process = launch_kernel(cmd, **scrubbed_kwargs)
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 169, in launch_kernel
raise ex
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 157, in launch_kernel
proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in init
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "c:\users\honey\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```